# VS code could not fetch remote environment

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I found that I cannot connect to the remote machine today...
In the log panel, it shows "Got connection 1 & 2," but I cannot open the terminal, and it starts to reconnect again soon.
Eventually, the error "Could not fetch remote environment" prompts.

In the log file, I found

```
*
* Visual Studio Code Server
*
* By using the software, you agree to
* the Visual Studio Code Server License Terms (https://aka.ms/vscode-server-license) and
* the Microsoft Privacy Statement (https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacystatement).
*
Server bound to 127.0.0.1:34309 (IPv4)
Extension host agent listening on 34309

[10:42:28] 




[10:42:28] Extension host agent started.
Got delay-shutdown request while in shutdown timeout, delaying
[10:42:28] Got delay-shutdown request while in shutdown timeout, delaying
Cancelling previous shutdown timeout
[10:42:28] Cancelling previous shutdown timeout
[10:42:28] Started initializing default profile extensions in extensions installation folder. file:///home/yuyan/.vscode-server/extensions
[10:42:28] Completed initializing default profile extensions in extensions installation folder. file:///home/yuyan/.vscode-server/extensions
[10:42:28] [127.0.0.1][dacc3eba][ManagementConnection] New connection established.
[10:42:28] [127.0.0.1][0b5ebe2b][ExtensionHostConnection] New connection established.
[10:42:28] [127.0.0.1][0b5ebe2b][ExtensionHostConnection] <145074> Launched Extension Host Process.
Got delay-shutdown request while in shutdown timeout, delaying
[10:43:17] Got delay-shutdown request while in shutdown timeout, delaying
Cancelling previous shutdown timeout
[10:43:17] Cancelling previous shutdown timeout
Got delay-shutdown request while in shutdown timeout, delaying
[10:43:33] Got delay-shutdown request while in shutdown timeout, delaying
Cancelling previous shutdown timeout
[10:43:33] Cancelling previous shutdown timeout
Got delay-shutdown request while in shutdown timeout, delaying
[10:43:50] Got delay-shutdown request while in shutdown timeout, delaying
Cancelling previous shutdown timeout
[10:43:50] Cancelling previous shutdown timeout
Got delay-shutdown request while in shutdown timeout, delaying
[10:44:11] Got delay-shutdown request while in shutdown timeout, delaying
Cancelling previous shutdown timeout
[10:44:11] Cancelling previous shutdown timeout
Got delay-shutdown request while in shutdown timeout, delaying
[10:44:32] Got delay-shutdown request while in shutdown timeout, delaying
Cancelling previous shutdown timeout
[10:44:32] Cancelling previous shutdown timeout
[10:44:32] [127.0.0.1][0b5ebe2b][ExtensionHostConnection] <145074> Extension Host Process exited with code: 0, signal: null.
Cancelling previous shutdown timeout
[10:44:32] Cancelling previous shutdown timeout
Last EH closed, waiting before shutting down
[10:44:32] Last EH closed, waiting before shutting down
```

My vscode version is shown below

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have tried multiple previous versions, and re-install the extension for multiple times but the issue is still there.

Thank you for any suggestion and help!!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/883Jj.png